# Whats the easiest way to merge meshes in collection?

Tags: modeling, texturing, scene, collections

[image]

Hello, so I copied a lot of the same object as the picture shows and want all the selected meshes to be one, so I can scale and color them all at the same time.
Is there a way to do that?

Best G

Comment: If L0Lock has answered your question it'd be helpful if you accepted it by clicking the checkmark next to it.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

You can join them by pressing <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>, but you also don't need to join objects into one in order to scale and color them at the same time.

You can have the same material for as many objects you want, just do <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> → Link material. You can edit the UVs of multiple objects at the same time.